# SEO impact of hosting large images externally

Tags: seo, web-hosting, images

As I have lot's of images on page and small hosting space, I would like to host them somewhere else.

I've read that it can have negative aspect on SEO, but what if I make small high compressed thumbnail on site and large image galleries will load from external source? Will it be the same?

Also, as Picassa offers up to 16MP free image hosting, I would like to host my images there and link them with my site gallery. Is this a good practise? Is possible that links can be changed one day or am I violating their rules?

Comment: Where the images reside does not matter as long as they download quickly. That is the key. On the flip-side, you would be better off increasing your hosting plan or finding another host. It's up to you. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

For the first point as @closetnoc points out the image host does not really make a difference to SEO. Take all of the large website out there, frequently images are hosted on a CDN with a completely different domain name and yet there is no issue. What is taken into consideration is load time, if you use a hosting provider for your images that will take a long time to load from then you will see your ranking go down.

As for the other point with Picasa, they may provide direct links for image however buried somewhere in the terms and conditions (came across it a while back but can't remember where in the T&C's I saw it) hot linking is not allowed. I know of a few websites back in the day that from day dot had their galleries loaded into Picasa and where hotlinking images from Picasa to their websites to limit the server plan they needed but only several months ago I saw a number of those sites suddenly loose all of their images as they could no longer display them on their sites from Picasa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've readed somewhere, that when your site loading images mostly from external sources, it has a bit negative impact on seo as it looks like you "don't have your own content"